# How do I get back the older way of (not) displaying dead key presses?

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint, gtk, dead-keys

Some characters in my language (Czech) are typed using 'dead keys' (key presses that don't move the caret) followed by a letter receiving the diacritics prepared in the previous dead key stroke.

The old way was that nothing was displayed at the dead key press only.
After upgrading from Linux Mint 19.3 (x64, Cinnamon) to 21 (the same arch and window manager), the dead key press displays a diacritics symbol to be added to the following letter.

How do I get the old way of *not* displaying anything until the final letter?

[image: keystrokes and what's displayed]

```
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     cz
options:    grp:win_space_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwertz)
types:      complete
compat:     complete+ledscroll(group_lock)
symbols:    pc+cz+inet(evdev)+group(win_space_toggle)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwertz)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+cz+inet(evdev)+group(win_space_toggle)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

**UPDATE 1**: It affects GTK applications (like `xed` text editor, Gnome terminal, Chrome, LibreOffice) while Qt applications like `notepadqq` work the old (desired) way.

`set -x XMODIFIERS @im=none` did not help

**UPDATE 2**: Installing `ibus` (Intelligent Input Bus - core) package introduces the problem *also* to Qt applications.

Comment: could you please add the output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` command in terminal?

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>This was most probably a bug, which disappeared after the last update:</del>

<del>less /var/log/apt/history.log</del>

<del>Upgrade: libxapp1:amd64 (2.2.14+vanessa, 2.2.15+vanessa),
xapps-common:amd64 (2.2.14+vanessa, 2.2.15+vanessa),
warpinator:amd64 (1.2.13+vanessa, 1cinnamon:amd64.2.14+vanessa),
libmuffin0:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa),
bulky:amd64 (2.4, 2.5),
muffin-common:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa),
cinnamon:amd64 (5.4.11+vanessa, 5.4.12+vanessa),
webapp-manager:amd64 (1.2.4, 1.2.5),
cinnamon-control-center-data:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa),
gir1.2-meta-muffin-0.0:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa),
libcinnamon-control-center1:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa),
cinnamon-common:amd64 (5.4.11+vanessa, 5.4.12+vanessa),
mintreport:amd64 (1.3.4, 1.3.5),
gir1.2-xapp-1.0:amd64 (2.2.14+vanessa, 2.2.15+vanessa),
cinnamon-control-center:amd64 (5.4.6+vanessa, 5.4.7+vanessa)</del>

<del>I suspect `cinnamon:amd64` was the cause of the problem.</del>

Wrong. I must have set it and the setting applied after logging out/in. It doesn't have anything to do with the update.
After installing Mint 21 to a new computer, the problem was back and no updating helped.

**Correct answer:**
Start `minlocale-im` (e.g. using Alt-F2).
Set input method framework to `XIM` (the select is on the top of the window).
Logout/login (or restart your computer).